CCTV control box connector
Can somebody help identify this connector. It's a plug on the circuit board of a CCTV control box. The 2 pins are 8 mm apart and at the other end of the wiring is a power on/off rocker switch. The plugs dimensions are L 18 x W 12 x H 5 mm.


Welcome! Have you tried Identiconn? https://connectorbook.com/identification.html

It looks like a custom OEM design.

My Identiconn utility identifies that as an ancient JST "V" connector. The JST part number is 2P-SVF.
LCSC has them.

Thank you lads for the help. It was indeed a JST connector 2P-SVF.

@LeonardRyan Please accept this answer by clicking the check mark to its left. This helps us identify questions that have been answered satisfactorily.
